# How can I execute cocos2d-js html file?

Tags: cocos2d-js

I made a cocos2d-js project on OSX.
And I debuged it on WebStorm.
It worked well.
So I just clicked index.html file. but it didn't work. just black screen.
I put all files on the web server and tried again.
Web brower console said `http://localhost:8080/html5/project.json` 404 not found.
but the file was in same folder.
I want to execute it on local server and just click.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the project directory, start new terminal.

Then: `cocos run -p web`

This will run your game for Web, as `-p` stands for `platform`

Also note, that sometimes you will need to clear the browser's cached images and files after changes that affect files or images.